# Cannot create file with Jupyter Notebook running in Docker in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Docker Toolbox for Windows v 18.09 in Windows 10 Version 10.0.19041 Build 19041 and am trying to run a docker container to run Jupiter Notebook with Pyspark.
I am using Windows Powershell to execute docker commands
`docker run hello-world` works fine so I can assume that Dockers has been installed correctly. Infact, I had go down to Toolbox v 18.09 before I could get hello world to work.
i use the following command to run the pyspark container

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 --volume=//C/Users/prith/pydev://home/jovyan/work jupyter/pyspark-notebook
```

from the C:/Users/prith/pydev directory that is mapped to the work directory of the container. The // is slash is required because i am working with Windows. the notebook shows up in http://192.168.99.100:8888 as expected and I can login with the token.
Then the problem starts when i try to create a new notebook or even a text file, I get a permission denied error. Evidently the container cannot write to 'some' directory. I have used Windows filesystem properties to give Everyone all privileges on this particular directory and have also run the Powershell in Adminstrtor mode ( to simulate Ubuntu sudo ..) but nothing works. 
Interestingly, I can write into the directory located above the work directory in the container but then I cannot access files written into that directory from Windows because I have mapped my local windows directory to /home/jovyan/work 
What do what i want?  I want to create Jupyter notebooks in the container and save them in Windows
I know all this works like a charm in Linux-Ubuntu, but unfortunately I am stuck with Windows 10. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you forgot to add the directory you're trying to mount to **FILE SHARING**.

Please, do `right-click on docker icon (in system tray)` -> `Settings` -> `Resources` -> `FILE SHARING`

Then, add your local directory.

Finally, if it doesn't work, try to mount volume with `--volume="C:\Users\prith\pydev":/home/joyvan/work`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am not using Docker for Windows, because my Win10 apparently does not support it. Hence I am using Docker Toolbox for Windows where I do not have this option of changing the settings. However I did solve the problem with this option in the command :  --volume='/c/Users/Public/PyDev'://home/jovyan/work   Please note that putting a colon after C: throws an error

Answer (score 0):

this command seems to work

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 --volume='/c/Users/Public/PyDev'://home/jovyan/work jupyter/pyspark-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```